# Not Finding Application Manifest - Progressive Web Applications

Tags: html, json, progressive-web-apps

I am currently trying to turn a Single Page Application that I have been developing into a Progressive Web Application but I seem to be falling at the first hurdle. I am trying to add the application manifest to the project but when I open it in Google Chrome Dev Tools it cannot find it. Below is the error I get from the developer tools.

[image]

In the next image I am showing my directory an as you can see the manifest.json is in the same directory as the index.html file.

[image]

Finally in the index.html file I have linked the manifest.json file as shown in the next image.

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions it would be massively appreciated and if you need any more information I will be happy to add it in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the manifest.json into `.angular-cli.json` "assets" array:
[image]